# Horizontall scroll in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I am using macbook pro 13" and running windows 8.1 on it (Bootcamp). I installed android studio (IDE for developing android app). I am wondering on how can i scroll horizontally (left to right or right to left via touchpad or magic mouse) on the IDE - editor itself?? Just like in Visual studio, i can just use my two finger and swipe left to right to scroll the editor for touchpad and magic mouse from left to right as well.

[Screenshot scroll the editor horizontal via touchpad or magic mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9D4R.png)

Answer (score 17):

The lack of support for touchpad/mouse horizontal scrolling was added to the [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115509).

Until it's fixed, you can use this shortcut:
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + `Mouse Scroll`

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/mouse-reference.html)

Comment: Is there other way without pressing shift + mouse scroll? like editing a specific settings... Since the touchpad or magic mouse of apple support sideway scroll???

Comment: Alright thanks! I hope this will be fixed especially for macbook pro or mac computer that is running on windows via bootcamp

Comment: not working for me, Android studio 3.3.2 macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Answer (score -1):

Go to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart, select "Invalidate and Restart."

Comment: you need to elaborate more.